# Downtack diacritic above character

Tags: accents, tipa

I need to add a downtack symbol above a character. The following example shows something close to what I want using the \top symbol, but the diacritic is way too big (it should be similar in scale to the other accents). I would ideally like to do this in TIPA, if possible, since I'm encoding all my other phonetic symbols with TIPA. I know how to combine and scale other symbols using TIPA, as shown in the MWE, but I couldn't figure out how to add this particular symbol in TIPA.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 

\begin{document}

    This is basically what I want, but the diacritic is too big, next to some other accents for comparison: 
{${\accentset{\top}{\text{a}}}$} á à ã
    
    Here's an TIPA accent I built for an apostrophe above a character: 
    \textipa{\tipaUpperaccent[.6ex]{\lower.8ex\hbox{\super{'}}}{a}}
    
        \end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{accents,scalerel}

\begin{document}

    This is basically what I want: 
    {${\accentset{\scalerel*{\mathsf{T}}{,}}{\text{a}}}$}
    {${\accentset{\scalerel*{\mathsf{T}}{\i}}{\text{a}}}$}
    
    Here's an TIPA accent, got it  centered: 
    \textipa{\tipaUpperaccent[.5ex]{\lower.8ex\hbox{\super{%
    \scalerel*{\mathsf{T}}{,}}}}{a}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!